# Can't get requery to work from form/subform

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Background:
I am trying to add a new form to an old Access database that was created with Access 2003. Previous forms were based on tables, but the fields for the new form are based on a query.

I have a form called MasterList with subform MasterList_Sub. MasterList contains textboxes that I want to use to filter MasterList_Sub, along with a search and clear button. MasterList_Sub is displayed beneath.

I modified the VBA for the search button from the other forms, but it does not seem to work. Here is the code from a working form:

```
Private Sub SEARCH_Click()
Forms!mrtgref!Mrtgref_sub.Requery
End Sub
```

My code is simply

```
Private Sub SEARCH_Click()
Forms!MasterList!MasterList_Sub.Requery
End Sub
```

When I press the search button something appears to happen, but the subform does not update. I'm new to programming for Access, but based on what I've read this code looks too simple, like I'm missing something. I can't find any other VBA modules in the DB, and the fields are set up similarly to the other DBs. Any ideas on how to proceed from here?

Also, I've tried some other syntax, and when it doesn't work I get an error that starts with "Mortgagee Inquiry can't find..." Where is it getting the name Mortgagee Inquiry from?

Comment: Please clarify: Is the subform recordsource based on a query, and if so, please post the sql. If a query, does it filter on the form fields? Second, is the subform linked to the main form using the 'Link Master / Child' pointers?

Comment: The subform is based on a query, and the SQL is below. I do not have anything in the link master/child fields. The other forms I'm looking at for examples also have these fields empty, and they are working. I did try using MRTG_CD for link master and it would then work for that field, but not for any other. I would prefer any field (12 in all) be usable as a filter

Comment: SELECT Mortgagee.MORTGAGEE_CD, Mrtglist.MRTG_TB, Mortgagee.PLCY_MRTG_CO_NAME1, Mortgagee.PLCY_STREET_ADDR1, Mortgagee.PLCY_CITY_NAME, Mortgagee.PLCY_STATE_CODE, Mortgagee.PLCY_ZIP_CODE, Mrtglist.MRTG_TYPE, Mrtglist.MRTG_CNT, Mortgagee.BILL_MRTG_CO_NAME1, Mortgagee.BILL_STREET_ADDR1, Mortgagee.BILL_CITY_NAME, Mortgagee.BILL_STATE_CODE, Mortgagee.BILL_ZIP_CODE
FROM Mortgagee INNER JOIN Mrtglist ON Mortgagee.MORTGAGEE_CD = Mrtglist.MRTG_CD;

Comment: I see no link between your main and your subform that would filter records, thus that's the reason this is not working. You have several choices, but the most straight forward is to use the main form VBA to set a filter for the subform: Me.MasterList_Sub.Form.Filter = "<somevalue>"  Me.MasterList_Sub.Form.FilterOn= true

Answer (score 1):

`MasterList_Sub` is a subform control. `.Requery` is a method of the Form itself therefore you need to add `.Form` before `.Requery`.

The structure:

```
Forms!MainForm!SubformControl.Form.Requery
```

In your case:

```
Forms!MasterList!MasterList_Sub.Form.Requery
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense to me, but still isn't working. It seems like something is happening in the background, but the subform does not update.